# Create vector of results from For loop with decimal index

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to run the following for loop and create a single vector with the results from each iteration.

```
for x=0.2:0.1:1,
        a=quadgk(h,0.2,x)
    end
```

I have tried different methods that usually work, but the problem is that the 'x' in the 'quadgk' function must be a scalar.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I would avoid using anything other than integers for your iterator `x`. Try using `a = zeros(9,1);for x = 1:9,a(x) = quadgk(h,0.2,(x+1)/10); end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to put results of each iteration into `a`. You can do the following:

```
count=0;
for x=0.2:0.1:1
    count=count+1;
    a(count)=quadgk(h,0.2,x)
end
```